# Installing Ubuntu inside Windows 7 without internet connection [offline mode]

Tags: wubi

I downloaded `ubuntu-12.04-amd64.iso` and created a bootable USB. I tried installing it (by running `wubi.exe` in Windows).

But the installer started downloading `ubuntu-12.04.2-wubi-amd64.tar.xz` (524 MB). My internet connection is too slow to download this file in one stretch. Is there any way to do this in offline mode?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use wubi? Dual booting from grub is usually faster and more stable.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put both wubi and ubuntu iso(which you downloaded) in same folder(try to put wubi and ubuntu iso only no other files in that folder) and run wubi it will work.

You don't need to download wubi from website, just open ubuntu iso file in winrar and you can find wubi as last file, extract only wubi outside.

You should disconnect your internet connection before running wubi.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get `ubuntu-12.04-amd64.iso` because the latest is `ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`. Wubi will reject an `iso` if it doesn't match the latest releases, or the online `md5sum` check fails.

If you run the `wubi.exe` you don't need a bootable USB. Just the `iso` and `wubi.exe`.

This is what to do if you want to install Wubi offline:

1. Download the latest `iso` for the release you want
2. Download the latest matching `wubi.exe` for the same release
3. Save both in the same directory before running `wubi.exe`.

If Wubi downloads the diskimage `ubuntu-12.04.2-wubi-amd64.tar.xz` then it's likely that it's not finding the `iso` (not in same folder) or it's corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

One best thing that can be done is download the wubi installer of the same version as the iso,

If it is windows 7, you need tools like daemon tools, which could mount the iso image. In Windows 8, this feature is already present.

Now run the downloaded wubi.exe installer, and no need of usb or cd.

Hope this works fine, if it doesn't, let us know.